# Calling WCF Service Contract/Method without Service Name in the url

Tags: wcf, iis-7, url-rewriting, hosting

My WCF service is at this location

```
http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6040/service.svc/
```

in IIS7.5 with two contracts `SubmitReturn` and `GetForward`.

But client calls the service at

```
http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6040/SubmitReturn/232323
```

on the root i.e. without service name in the url but the service should be called like this

```
 http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6040/service.svc/SubmitReturn/123456789
```

So how can I make the WCF service available at

```
http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6040/
```

rather than at

```
http:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6040/service.svc/
```

at the root of IIS?

Comment: Is is a WCF Rest Service ?

Comment: Yes.Its a Rest Service.And I tried Url rewriting also but giving 404 error. here's my rewriting url config                           <rule name="Service" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/service.svc/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

Answer (score 0):

refer to 
[Creating WCF service without .svc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581881/creating-wcf-service-without-svc-file)

and link mentioned in one of the comments - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2009/10/27/activation-without-svc-files-config-based-activation-cba.aspx

Comment: It didn't work.Even I tried Url rewriting but giving 404 error.

Comment: check this link - http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/fileless-activation-of-wcf-service-in-net-4-0/

Comment: Thanx but this will help if there is no .svc file on the server,and they are calling the service name in the uri like this ***ServicName.svc*** or without the extension ***ServicName***.

Answer (score 0):

I was following this link for URL rewriting (***Good link***)

***www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules***

And url rewriting works fine for "article.aspx"(go to the link provided above to see) on my server.

But for my service it is giving error "***Endpoint Not Found***".

This is my latest web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MessageWebService.MessageWebService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:6040"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="MessageWebService.IMessageWebService"
          bindingConfiguration="MessageWebService"
          behaviorConfiguration="MessageWebService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MessageWebService"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MessageWebService">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Fail bad requests">
          <match url="." />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="localhost" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite to MessageWebService.MessageWebService.svc">
          <match url="*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/MessageWebService.MessageWebService.svc/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```